# Use PostGIS to get Web Mercator tiles covering a polygon

Tags: postgis

I have a polygon in a PostGIS database and I need a list of the Web Mercator tile X/Y pairs that cover the polygon at a particular zoom level. Let's say the polygon is the boundary of the France and the zoom level is 15. For an example of what I mean by X/Y pairs, the slippy map on [this](https://www.maptiler.com/google-maps-coordinates-tile-bounds-projection) site presents the concept visually.

What I've tried so far is using `ST_SquareGrid()` to create a level-15 grid/graticule for the entire world, and then intersecting it with the boundary of France. The grid took forever to generate and I didn't realize it would be ~1 billion polygons. So far, any operation against that grid has been very expensive and slow, even after indexing. I'm wondering if there's a more straightforward way of doing this that I'm missing.

Comment: Not a PostGIS solution, so only commenting, but I have found https://github.com/mapbox/mercantile handy for doing this (Python/CLI).

Comment: I highly recommend using https://mercantile.readthedocs.io/en/stable/cli.html#tiles instead of a geometric database operation.

Comment: This looks like a fantastic library, thank you @alphabetasoup and @bugmenot123! I haven't used Python in a while but I can dust it off and try this out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While this can be highly optimized algorithmically in a custom low-level implementation, if your *Polygons of Interest* exist in PostgreSQL/PostGIS already I dare say don't bother - just do it right:

- `ST_SubDivide` your *POI*s; since indexation is useless here, you can run this on-the-fly
- create a coverage grid **per POI** and filter for `ST_Intersects`; since the vertex count per geometry is highly reduced above, intersection checks are much cheaper

```
WITH
  -- parameter injection, for convenience
  zoom(lvl, csize) AS (
    VALUES ( <ZOOM>, (2*PI()*6378137)/POW(2, <ZOOM>) )
  ),

  -- subdivide your polygons to minimize per-geometry vertex count
  poi AS (
    SELECT
      id, sdv AS geom
    FROM
      <POIs> AS ply,
      LATERAL ST_SubDivide(
        ST_Transform(ply.geom, 3857),
        <MAX_VERTICES>
      ) AS sdv
  )

-- get all covering tile indices for each POI
SELECT
  t.id AS poi_id,
  (grid.i, grid.j, z.lvl) AS index
FROM
  zoom as z,
  poi AS t,
  LATERAL ST_SquareGrid(z.csize, t.geom) AS grid

-- filter for those that actually intersect any of the subdivisions
WHERE
  ST_Intersects(t.geom, grid.geom)

-- return uniques only; much faster than a DISTINCT for multi-column
GROUP BY
  t.id, (grid.i, grid.j, z.lvl)
;
```

*This takes **~6s** on a 220k vertex boundary of France for `<ZOOM> = 15` & `<MAX_VERTICES> = 64`.*

---

If you plan to do this over and over, `ST_SubDivide` (with lower `<MAX_VERTICES>` value) your POIs into a separate table and run the main query on those.

Comment: This is incredible, thank you! One thing I'm noticing is that the origin of these tile indices is Web Mercator (0, 0), whereas vector tiles tend to index starting in the upper-left corner and increase rightward and downward, like a bitmap. (Google Maps and Mapbox do this, for instance.) In hindsight I should have been clearer in my question! I'm wondering how I might adapt this for an upper-left origin...