# Use PostGIS to get OSM tile coordinates covering a geometry linestring

Tags: postgis, openstreetmap

I have a linestring in SRID 4326 in my table. I would like to know which tiles the linestring crosses regarding a zoom level on OpenStreetMap. The solution found here looks to come close. [Use PostGIS to get Web Mercator tiles covering a polygon](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/445564/use-postgis-to-get-web-mercator-tiles-covering-a-polygon)

But the problem with the given answer, is that the coordinates do not match the z/x/y coordinates that a tileserver is using.

I'm still learning about different projections, it might be that that's where its going wrong?

Let's say I would like to have the coordinates for zoom level 14, This would be the SQL I'm running.

```
WITH
  -- parameter injection, for convenience
  zoom(lvl, csize) AS (
    VALUES ( 14, (2*PI()*6378137)/POW(2, 14) )
  ),

  -- subdivide your polygons to minimize per-geometry vertex count
  poi AS (
    SELECT
      id, sdv AS geom
    FROM
      <poistable> AS ply,
      LATERAL ST_SubDivide(
        ST_Transform(ply.geom, 3857),
        64
      ) AS sdv
      WHERE id='<id>'
  )

-- get all covering tile indices for each POI
SELECT
  t.id AS poi_id,
  (grid.i, grid.j, z.lvl) AS index
FROM
  zoom as z,
  poi AS t,
  LATERAL ST_SquareGrid(z.csize, t.geom) AS grid

-- filter for those that actually intersect any of the subdivisions
WHERE
  ST_Intersects(t.geom, grid.geom)

-- return uniques only; much faster than a DISTINCT for multi-column
GROUP BY
  t.id, (grid.i, grid.j, z.lvl)
;
```

But where i'm hoping to get tiles from the netherlands around(z=14 x=8480 y=5319), i'm getting (i=293 j=2875 z=14).

Is using a different SRID and size for st_squaregrid the solution.
Working with a size of 0.022 (length of tile at zoomlevel 14 according to https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Zoom_levels) and SRID 4326 gives the same results...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first post you reference, the same issue seems to happen as well (see the asker's comment to the answer). Here is a solution for you.

Background:

1. The center coordinate of the main Web Map Tiling systems is the top left corner of level 0.
2. `ST_SquareGrid()` returns tile numbers with an origin centered on the CRS Origin, in your case, with CRS 4326 or 3857, this is located at Lat = 0 & Lon = 0.
3. ST_SquareGrid coordinates will be `(0,0)` where the Web Map Tile index will be `(2^(level-1) , 2^(level-1))`. 2^(level-1) being half the vertical/horizontal amount of tiles at the zoom level) which brings you to the center of the overall tiling system.
4. This means that you need compensations of 2^(level-1) somewhere , depending on which Lat/Lon quadrant your geoetries are [See interactive tile numbering](https://www.maptiler.com/google-maps-coordinates-tile-bounds-projection/#1/0.51/19.96)

In your case, ff all your polygons are East from the prime meridian and in the Northern hemisphere,  you should be good with these formulas :

- X = 8192+i =8192+293= 8485
- Y = 8192-j = 8192-2875= 5317

This seem to match with your current results

Visual representation of both tiling systems:

[image]